# PC turns on for a few seconds, then shuts down

Tags: boot, memory, cpu, post

Yesterday, my PC began acting in a really strange way. When i powered it on, the fans (CPU fan, PSU fan and GPU fan) started spinning, but all turned off after around 3-4 seconds. No POST beeps or anything. The green power indicator light on the motherboard stayed on.

Now here is the interesting part. I initially thought it was faulty RAM, so when i removed the RAM it finally powered up, gave 3 POST beeps, the usual thing, so i went and bought new RAM.

When i came home and inserted the new RAM, same thing happened - fans power up, and turn off after 2-3 seconds.

Im stumped. What could be the problem of this? The fans spin fine when there is no RAM inside the motherboard, but start acting up when RAM is inserted in it, no matter how new/old it is.

Comment: What made you think the RAM was at fault? Has the computer had a similar problem before?

Comment: It's possible that the CPU is poorly seated or faulty.  Possible that the CPU cooler is improperly seated, leading to thermal shutdown (this normally takes 30 seconds or so).  You will have to try swapping individual parts in and out to determine what part is broken.  It's easiest if you have a whole second PC with compatible parts.

Comment: What's the motherboard model /cpu? If you didn't build it what's the manufacturer and model?